# setting height to wrap_content in Java makes the view deny all predefined XML attributes?

Tags: java, android, android-wrap-content

I have created a TextView in XML and have set some rules for it (for example `layout_bellow="something"`), and made it's height set to 0, so that when a button is clicked, it's height would be set to `wrap_content`. I wrote the code bellow for the button responsible for resizing, and below it is the XML code i wrote for the TextView. The problem is, when i click the button, the height becomes `match_parent`, the `layout_bellow` attribute gets ignored and it is drawn from the start of the parent layout, and width (that was set to `match_parent`) becomes `wrap_content`. Whats the problem? thanks.

the Button:

```
    btnExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height));
        }
    });
```

the XML:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstRow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                .
                .
                .
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/theTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/firstRow"
                android:text="lorem ipsom lorem ipsom">

        </RelativeLayout>
```

[EDIT: here's an image to demonstrate the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjV9K.png)

Comment: If you want to modify the `TextView`'s `LayoutParams`, get it from the `TextView` first - e.g., `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();` - make your changes on it, then set it back on the `TextView`. You're creating all new `LayoutParams`, so any attribute you don't explicitly set gets the default value, and any layout rules you don't add just won't happen, which is why the `layout_below` no longer works.

Comment: @MikeM. This seems to be my problem. But could you please write how i can change one param of the lp object (for example the height)?

Comment: The height is a public field in `LayoutParams`, so you'd just set it directly. For example, after the line I showed above - `lp.height = height; textView.setLayoutParams(lp);`.

Comment: This only allows me to set my height to a specific number, but not to wrap_content. Any way to do that?

Comment: Set it to `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`.

Comment: @MikeM. Awesome. It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem is you are creating new LayoutParams and setting it to the view. You have get the already set(xml) LayoutParams of the view and modify whichever you want to modify and set it back to the View.

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = textView.getLayoutParams();
//height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;or 100 or whatever
layoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: In this way i can only set the height to a specific number, but not to wrap_content. How can i do that?

Comment: Modified answer

Comment: It says height is final and cant be changed but codes in the comments above worked. Please change it so i can accept your answer.

Comment: @MrChips I have modified it.